# What's the most lightweight way to add onclick() to hundreds of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page, primarily used by mobile users (about 80% of my users), with about 350 `<input type="checkbox">` elements. When a checkbox is checked or unchecked, I want to call some javascript to save the state in local storage. When I created my page there were only about 100 elements so instead of making each element `<input type="checkbox" onclick="save();">` which seemed prone to typos or just plain forgetting to add the `onclick`, I added this to my `onload` function:

```
var input_elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for (var i = 0; i < input_elements.length; i++) {
    input_elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() { save(this); });
}
```

which works great but adds a small penalty to page load times -- which is getting worse as I add elements, and I'm expecting to keep adding another 100-150 each year.

Is there a "better" way of doing this, both in terms of reducing load times (especially for mobile users with slower browsers) and preventing me from making dumb typos that break something for my users but are hard for me to spot?

Comment: you can add event handler on some common parent - use event delegation mechanism

Comment: A small optimisation can be having a named function and using it as handler. `.addEventListener("click", myHandler)`. This will have first argument as event and context as element

Comment: You could bind it to the document like: document.addEventListener('click', function (e) { if (e.target.type == 'checkbox') { //do your thing} }, false);

Comment: @drewbenn, you're welcome. posted as an answer

Comment: I don't think the handlers on the checkboxes will be slowing load time - I think having so many form elements on one page will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add event handler on some common parent, for example some wrapper `div` or `document` if there's no wrapper parent. Search for `event delegation mechanism` to get more information about this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a capturing click handler and test if the click was on a check box:

```
function checkCheck(event) {
    if( event.target && event.target.type == "checkbox"){
      checkSave( event.target)
    }
}
function checkSave( checkBox) {
    // do something for click on checkbox element
    console.log("checkbox %s, checked: %s", checkBox.id, checkBox.checked);
}
window.addEventListener("click", checkCheck, true);
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
```